# Average standardized distance between units?

Tags: statistics, summation, mahalanobis-distance

Let $$ \pmb{X} = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11}& \cdots& x_{1j}& \cdots& x_{1p} \\ \vdots& & \vdots & & \vdots \\ x_{i1} & \cdots & x_{ij} & \cdots & x_{ip} \\ \vdots && \vdots && \vdots\\ x_{n1} & \cdots & x_{nj} & \cdots & x_{np} \end{pmatrix}. $$

Let $$\pmb{x}_i^{(ind)} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{x_{i1}-\overline{x}_1}{\sqrt{n}s_1} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{x_{ij}-\overline{x}_j}{\sqrt{n}s_j} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{x_{i1}-\overline{x}_p}{\sqrt{n}s_p} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
such that 
$$\pmb{X}_R = \begin{pmatrix} \pmb{x}_1^{(ind)^{\top}} \\ \vdots \\ \pmb{x}_i^{(ind)^{\top}} \\ \vdots \\ \pmb{x}_n^{(ind)^{\top}} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Moreover, define the *standardized Euclidean distance* as 
$$d^2(\pmb{x}_i^{(ind)}, \pmb{x}_l^{(ind)}) = \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{(x_{ij}-x_{lj})^2}{ns_j^2}.$$

I have three questions, two of which I think I already answered.

1. What is the sum of the squares of all the standardized distances between all the pairs of units, i.e.,
   $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n d^2(\pmb{x}_i^{(ind)}, \pmb{x}_l^{(ind)}),$$
2. What is the sum of the squares of all the standardized distances between all the units and their mean vector?
3. What is the average standardized distance between the units?

---

1. For this question, the answer is $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n d^2(\pmb{x}_i^{(ind)}, \pmb{x}_l^{(ind)}) = \cdots = 2pn.$$
2. For this, the answer is
   $$\sum_{i=1}^n  d^2(\pmb{x}_i^{(ind)}, \pmb{\overline{x}}^{(ind)}) = \cdots = p$$
3. This is where I'm stuck. I don't know what to compute. Should I use the Mahalanobis distance?

---

**Edit:** I have the following for question 3:
$$\mathbb{E}[d^2(\pmb{x}_i^{(ind)}, \pmb{x}_l^{(ind)})] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^p \frac{(x_{ij}-x_{lj})^2}{ns_j^2} \right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^p \frac{1}{s_j^2} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[(x_{ij}-x_{lj})^2]}_{=s_j^2} = \frac{p}{n}, $$
do you agree?